# position css arrow half way down div

Tags: css

I have a css arrow positioned at the size of my div.

Here is a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/lasikokimu/edit?html,css,output) that shows it in action.

How can I position the arrow half way down the div no matter what height the div is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd do it by changing the way you calculate top, so in this case using "calc" and by subtracting border-width.

`top: calc(50% - 10px)`

Here is a working [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/kibegavuno/1/edit?html,css,output).

Answer (score 6):

When you use `position: absolute` you can center things like this:

```
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
transform: translateY(-50%);
```

`top: 50%` assigns 50% of the parent's height to top

`transform: translateY(-50%)` moves the element up by 50% of the element's height.

This method works regardless of the element's height or the parent's height.

You can also use it to center things horizontally:

```
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
transform: translateX(-50%);
```

or both vertically and horizontally:

```
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

http://jsbin.com/lixisidezu/1/edit?html,css,output

Answer (score 2):

You don't actually need CSS3 for this; CSS2 suffices and without too much hackishness: http://jsbin.com/civijuvofo/1/edit?html,css,output - the essence is to do e.g. `top: 50%; margin-top: -10px;`.

In particular, you can position the white+gray triangles half-way down box with `top: 50%;`.  Then they're too low - they start at the 50% midpoint, but they descend down to 50% + 2*borderwidth.  You *could* use css3 `calc` to compensate, or a css3 transform, but the most compatible hack is simply to apply a negative top margin equal to the border width.

That means your "arrow" fan-out then looks as follows in CSS:

```
.container:before, .container:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 100%;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-color: transparent;
    border-style: solid;
}

.container:before {
    margin-top:  -11px;
    border-width: 11px;  
    border-right-color: #dedede;
}

.container:after {
    margin-top:  -10px;
    border-width: 10px;
    border-right-color: #fff;
}
```

This 'll work cross-browser in pretty much any browser released in the past 10-15 years.  I'm not sure about IE7 :-).